# Authentication within python script

Tags: python, authentication

I'm writing a master-control script to control our infrastructure. Security is a major concern so I'd like to address two issues:

I want the user to be able to execute the application then be prompted to 'login' to the program using the root credentials on the system(Linux - Ubuntu). Failure to authenticate will trigger an email event and lock the program. Can I authenticate against /etc/passwd? And how can I lockout the application?

Second, how do I secure the application from modification? I may have to hard-code certain attributes into the application. What are the ideal permissions for a script to be executed but not edited?

Comment: Perhaps you should make the script only executable by a superuser? Then require the user to use sudo / su to execute the script.

Comment: As for your second inquiry, python is not really a suitable candidate for obfuscation. You could ship the compiled `.pyc` files only, which are a little more harder to alter.

Comment: I should have mentioned. This script will reside on one of three C&C servers(Command and control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a non-trivial solution, the most secure way to do this is taking a client/server approach, making your master-control script a system service, only readable and runnable by root. You can fire up the service via `init.d` startup infrastructure.

When the service starts, you'd need to open a socket or RPC server to handle your control commands. On Python this can easily be done using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

To authenticate via `/etc/passwd` you can use the [crypt](http://docs.python.org/library/crypt.html) and [pwd](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html) Python modules.

Comment: That is a very cool suggestion. I'm going to explore this. Will this prevent any hard-coded logins from being discovered?

Comment: @Jeffrey I suggest you avoid hard-coded logins since they can be brute forced. Also, if your source code gets leaked, the attacker would easily have acces to the credentials. The internal /etc/passwd auth mechanism has an auth token ring that helps the mitigation of a brute force attack.

Comment: Absolutely. I only mentioned that as an example because I actually want to stash other information in the script(non-login information) without worrying about it being read by anyone with access to the script and a text editor.